# Autoprefixer for partially prefixed CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vendor-prefix, autoprefixer

I need to manipulate CSS files on the server and I recently discovered [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) library.

My issue is - my css files have prefix depending on the browser which was used. 
For eg. My css code is something like this -

```
.newclass
{
    -moz-transition:.3s all;
}
```

Autoprefixer doesn't work here and requires the css to be

```
.newclass
{
    transition:.3s all;
}
```

to generate

```
.newclass
{
    transition:.3s all;
    -moz-transition:.3s all;
    -ms-transition:.3s all;
    -o-transition:.3s all;
    -webkit-transition:.3s all;
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve the same result with my original CSS (a prefixed property instead of non-prefixed one)? 
Or is there any other library that can help me achieve the same thing other than Autoprefixer?

Comment: Can't you just manually fix your css instead?

Answer (score 3):

This is by design. Autoprefixer deliberately ignores any prefixes that don't precede an unprefixed declaration so they can be used if they are absolutely necessary without being overwritten, which would lead to undesired side effects.

For example, the output you've given in your question is *not* the output that would be generated if you ran Autoprefixer right now with the default settings. Assuming it *did* overwrite your `-moz-` prefix, it'd discard it entirely because [the prefix is no longer needed as of Firefox 16 which came out almost two years ago](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/16). The actual output would be:

```
.newclass
{
    -webkit-transition:.3s all;
            transition:.3s all;
}
```

Now, you *could* just run Autoprefixer with an option to accommodate older versions of Firefox (`Firefox >= 4`) and other browsers, but you will still have to remove the prefix(es) from your CSS if you want Autoprefixer to process it. You cannot expect Autoprefixer to assume it can do whatever it wants with prefixes explicitly declared in your CSS.

[This section](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#disabling) of the documentation has a different example, but the principle is the same:

> ### Disabling
>
> Autoprefixer was designed to have no interface – it just works. If you need some browser specific hack just write prefixed property after unprefixed.
>
> ```
> a {
>     transform: scale(0.5);
>     -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
> }
> ```

Comment: Yeah, I understand the dynamics of Autoprefixer and how it is supposed to work. I got confused because I was using the PHP version and it was resulting in the desired result while the CLI version doesn't have the same effect. I ended up "hacking" the autoprefixer library